# Mark js marker cancels the user selection

Tags: javascript, rangy

I'm using mark.js to mark the user selection text on some html element (like an ordinary text editor). However, the mark js marker cancels the user selection and its disapear so i can't use it anymore.

I have tried to use `rangy.saveSelection()` and `rangy.restoreSelection()` but it didn't help.

My code is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#p").on('mouseup', function() {
                $("#p").unmark({
                    done: function() {
                        $("#p").mark(window.getSelection().toString(), {
                            seperateWordSearch: false
                });
            }
        })
    });
})
```